# Text wrapping around figures with \cutwin and \itemize for long body text

Tags: header-footer, itemize, line-spacing, wrapfigure, adjustbox

community,

I would like to wrap text around images using \cutwin in \itemize with long body texts. I got three problems:

1. The linespacing (initial setup \onehalfspacing) shrinks largely (see attached picture).
2. When text of the first adjustbox is long, the second adjustbox jumps to next page (see attached picture).
3. Adjustbox overlaps the headers.

Could you please help me to fix them? Thank you.

[image]

Below is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.25cm,headsep=8pt, headheight=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% For wrapping text around text
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Itemize
\usepackage[calc]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}%
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

% Spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

% Caption
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period}


% header and page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Left header}
\chead{}
\rhead{\textit{Right heaader}}

\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage \ of 2}
\rfoot{}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.5cm}


\begin{document}

% Part 1
% The first figure
\opencutright 
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{% setup the image to be placed in the cutout 
    \begin{flushright}
    \begin{measuredfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.80\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption of Fig. 1 here.}
    \end{measuredfigure}
    \end{flushright}
}

% Text of Part 1
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=b,vspace=0bp,minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,wide = 0pt]
        \begin{cutout}{3}{0.6\linewidth}{0pt}{9}
        \item\textbf{Elastic instability and ideal strength of nano-metals:}
        \Blindtext[1][4] 
        \end{cutout}
    \end{itemize}
\end{adjustbox}


% Part 2 
% The figure for Part 2
\opencutleft
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{% 
    \begin{measuredfigure}
     \includegraphics[width=0.80\linewidth]{example-image-b.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption of Fig. 2 here.}
    \end{measuredfigure}
}

% Text for Part 2
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=C,vspace=0bp,minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,wide = 0pt]
        \begin{cutout}{3}{0pt}{0.6\linewidth}{9}
        \item \textbf{Nano-materials with abnormal properties:}
        \Blindtext[1][4]
        \end{cutout}
    \end{itemize}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why you want to use `cutwin`? You could for example use the `wrapfig` package to make the code a lot cleaner and achieve the same effect, as shown [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/wrapping_text_around_figures). Only thing to consider is that you cannot use the itemize environment in combination with wrapfigure, but you could manually simulate that using symbols like `$\bullet$`.

Comment: Using `cutwin` to set text above the image automatically. For `wrafig`, as far as I know I need to it manually to set text above the image.